# JQuery clone and Onchange Events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with rows and `input`/`select` form elements. At the bottom row i have a button to add a new row to the Table. Initially the table is empty with just one row with a button
Like this:

```
<form name="test" id="test" action="#" >
<table id="matrix">
  <tr id="1">
    <td><select class="parent" name="parent">
            <option value="C" label="C">C</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="P" label="P">P</option>
            <option value="B" label="B">B</option>           
        </select></td>        
    <td><div  id="my_data_1">
            <span title="parent_val"></span>
        </div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td colspan="3"><input type="button" class="add_new" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Now when i click on the button with the `add_new` class i clone the first row, increment its id and then insert it above the last row.

The issue is that i have an onchange event attached to the select with class parent as

```
$('#matrix').on('change', 'select.parent_type', function() {
    var RowID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');   
    var attributes_div = $('#matrix tr#'+RowID).find('div#my_data'+RowID );
    new_id = GetParentIDFormat(attributes_div, 3);
    $(attributes_div +"span[title='parent_val']").html(new_id);

});
```

When i added two or more rows, the change function changes the Value for SPAN "parent_val" for ALL the rows rather than the specific row whose SELECT parent was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few errors, without the `GetParentIDFormat` function, I cannot provide a 100% solution, but here goes:

`'select.parent_type'` should be `'select.parent'`

`$('#matrix tr#'+RowID).find('div#my_data');` should be
`$('#' + RowID).find('.my_data');`.
Note that you require classes, as you cannot have multiple equivalent IDs.

`$(attributes_div +"span[title='parent_val']")`
Should be
`$("span[title='parent_val']", attributes_div)`

Resulting in:

```
$('#matrix').on('change', 'select.parent', function() {
    var RowID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); 
    var attributes_div = $('#' + RowID).find('.my_data');
    var new_id = GetParentIDFormat(attributes_div, 3);
    $("span[title='parent_val']", attributes_div).html(new_id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `attributes_div` variable points to a jQuery object, so you can't concatenate that with a string to get a selector to select the element you want. Instead just do this:

```
attributes_div.find('span[title="parent_val"]').html(new_id);
```

That will look for the `<span title="parent_val">` element inside of the specific `<div>` referenced by `attributes_div`, and therefore should be the single element you want.

However, note that if you're cloning that row, you can't use an ID of `my_data` on *all* of the `<div>` elements as they're supposed to be unique; consider changing to a class instead.